# Do I need to calibrate a model to use the Brier score?

Tags: probability, predictive-models, scoring-rules

When I use the [Brier score loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.brier_score_loss.html), do I need to [calibrate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) the model and then use the calibrated model's predictions as input into the Brier score loss?

If I just use a non-calibrated model's probabilities to compute the Brier score, is this approach sound or ok? The part of the article from Scikit-Learn that is not clear is this statement: [The Brier score loss] can be decomposed as the sum of refinement loss and calibration loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Brier loss (or scoring) function compares predicted probabilities to binary outcomes. If $p \in [0, 1]$ was predicted and $y \in \{0,1 \}$ materializes then the loss is $(p - y)^2$. So **NO**, how the probabilities where produced is irrelevant. However, it is critical that $p$ is interpreted as a prediction of $\mathbb{P} (Y=1)$, otherwise using the loss makes no sense.

The decomposition into refinement loss and calibration loss just highlights that the Brier score measures both, how sharp/refined and how well calibrated the predictions are. The loss value combines both assessments in one number.

Answer (score 2):

When you calibrate the model and then calculate the Brier score, you are calculating the Brier score of a two-stage model that first does some machine learning model and then does a calibration step. It is legitimate to calibrate a model, but the two-stage model is a different model than the one-state model, and the Brier score of the two-stage model does not apply to the one-stage model, which will (probably) have a different Brier score (so, no, you can calculate the Brier score without first calibrating).

Comment: In Scikit-Learn, predictions are given for both y=0 and y=1. Typically, I use the probability (prediction) for y=1. Does it matter which probability prediction to use when computing Brier score loss?

Comment: @JaneWayne That’s a wonderful question to ask as its own question. As far as I know, this is not addressed on here, and it’s not necessarily obvious why you should use $P(Y=1)$.